# Why does `Fn() -> T` constrain `T` but `Fn(T) -> T` does not

Tags: rust

The following code compiles fine:

```rust
struct StructA<F>(F);
impl<F, T> StructA<F> where F: Fn() -> T {}
```

Although `T` doesn't show up in `StructA`'s type parameters, it is still constrained due to the `where` clause. This trick is used, for example, in [`std::iter::Map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html#impl-Iterator) so `Map<I, F>` only needs two type parameters while the `impl<B, I, F> Iterator for Map<I, F>` takes three.

However the following code does not compile:

```rust
struct StructB<F>(F);
impl<F, T> StructB<F> where F: Fn(T) -> T {}
```

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `B` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/lib.rs:5:9
  |
5 | impl<F, T> StructB<F> where F: Fn(T) -> T {}
  |         ^ unconstrained type parameter

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0207`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

[**Playground Link**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=165c4a7c54291641bce47de4364fe5d7)

This is unintuitive, why would using `T` in more places make it less constrained? Is this intended or is it a limitation in Rust?

---

Note this also happens with regular traits, i.e. the desugared version of `Fn`:

```rust
trait FnTrait<Args> {
    type Output;
}

// Works
struct StructA<F>(F);
impl<F, T> StructA<F> where F: FnTrait<(), Output = T> {}

// Fails
struct StructB<F>(F);
impl<F, T> StructB<F> where F: FnTrait<(T,), Output = T> {}
```

[**Playground Link**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3c0f2b2ec0f657e452f7b747b0f3b73)

Comment: I seriously wonder if this is not a bug or just an implementation necessarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider what happens if we implement `Fn` manually (of course this requires nightly)...

```rust
#![feature(fn_traits, unboxed_closures)]

struct MyFunction;
impl<T> FnOnce<(T,)> for MyFunction {
    type Output = T;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, (v,): (T,)) -> T { v }
}
```

Now imagine your struct:

```rust
struct StructA<F>(F);
impl<F: FnOnce(T) -> T, T> StructA<F>{
    fn foo(self) -> T { (self.0)() }
}

let s: StructA<MyFunction> = ...;
s.foo(); // What is `T`?
```

While [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#generic-implementations) says:

> Generic parameters *constrain* an implementation if the parameter appears at least once in one of:
>
> - ...
> - As an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-types) in the [bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html) of a type that contains another parameter that constrains the implementation

This is inaccurate. Citing [the RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0447-no-unused-impl-parameters.html#detailed-design):

> Type parameters are legal if they are "constrained" according to the following inference rules:
>
> - ...
> - If `<T0 as Trait<T1...Tn>>::U == V` appears in the impl predicates, and `T0`...`Tn` are constrained and `T0 as Trait<T1...Tn>` is not the impl trait reference then `V` is constrained.

That is, *all* type parameters that appear in the trait should be constrained, not just one of them.

[I've opened an issue in the reference repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/1183).

Related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25041.

Answer (score 3):

You always need to be able to deduce the generic type parameters of an impl from the self type of the impl (and possibly the trait being implemented, if it's a trait impl). In the first case, `F: Fn() -> T`, it is possible to derive `T` from the self type `StructA<F>`. However, with the trait bound `F: Fn(T) -> T`, this is not possible.

The difference between the two cases results from the fact that the return type of the closure trait `Fn` is an associated type, while the argument types are generic parameters. In other words, you can only implement `Fn() -> T` for any type `F` once, and that implementation will have a fixed return type `T`. The trait `Fn(T) -> T`, on the other hand, could be implemented for multiple types `T` for the same `F`, so given `F` you can't deduce what `T` is in general.

In practice it is of course very uncommon that multiple `Fn` traits are implemented for the same type, and when only using closures it's even impossible. However, since it's *possible*, the compiler needs to account for it.